# не загружается объект из префаба

Tags: c#, unity3d

На канвасе в старом проекте был объект `RawImage`. я сделал из него как надо ( поместил в него что нужно ). и с делал префаб поместив его в каталог `Resources`. Назвал его `Player_enemy_0`. в коде пробую загрузить этот префаб вот так. `image = Resources.Load<RawImage> ( "Player_enemy_0" );`, но он не появляется в списке объектов и на экране. что делать? unity `2018.4.18f1`.

Comment: Instantiate(image,...) сделал?

Comment: Вроде пробывал, вроде писал что object is null.